# Pandas/BigQuery - TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: pandas, google-bigquery

I am trying to load data from a panda into BigQuery, but I'm met with the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 112, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._get_loc_duplicates
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

My code is:

```
    x = response['rows']

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x)
    
    
    # split the keys list into columns
    df[['query','device', 'page', 'date']] = pd.DataFrame(df['keys'].values.tolist(), index= df.index)

    # Drop the key columns
    result = df.drop(['keys'],axis=1)
    
    # Add a website identifier
    result['website'] = site_url
    result['country'] = "gbr"
    result['ctr'] = 1.5
    
    column_names = ["date", "query", "page", "clicks", "impressions", "ctr", "position", "website", "country", "device", "website"]

    result = result.reindex(columns=column_names)

    print(result.dtypes)
    


    print(result)

    # establish a BigQuery client
    client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE)
    dataset_id = BQ_DATASET_NAME
    table_name = BQ_TABLE_NAME
    # create a job config
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    # Set the destination table
    table_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id).table(table_name)
    job_config.write_disposition = 'WRITE_APPEND'

    load_job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(result, table_ref, job_config=job_config)
    load_job.result()
```

As far as I'm aware, I'm not trying to compare any str or int - so I don't understand where the error has come from.

I've tried checking the type of columns that the panda has, and they are all objects, apart from two (the ctr and the position. This seems correct.

I can't understand the error though. If I just display the dataframe, it works fine. As soon as I try and load into bigquery, I have the above error though.

Could anybody please advise? I've been searching for the past hour but can't find anything!

Thank you

Comment: Look at the error Trackback, there is a line with arrow pointing to the error statement

Comment: That seems to be from the pandas files though which I have just imported - not through any code I have written. Is it normal to change these?

Comment: Sometimes could be ""indirect" error caused by expanded codes generated by your code.  So, to trace to your code, check the traceback with arrow.  Often at the top of the traceback.

Comment: I'm a bit unsure of how to do that - which file should I be looking at?

Comment: The error message is something like:  `AttributeError: 'dict_items' object has no attribute 'values'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-112-38fda511f5ba> in <module>
----> 1 dict(d.items().values())
AttributeError: 'dict_items' object has no attribute 'values'`     You just need to look at the `---->` to get hint of which line of codes give the error.

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is at least indirectly related to having the same column name (website) for multiple columns. I found this question because I had the same problem. I noticed I had two identical column names so I made them unique. This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Same here! It was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Two equal columns names in the dataframe cause the error: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'.

Comment: This was already suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69713619/18145256).